# Converting C# to VB syntax

Tags: c#, vb.net, translation

I have a function in C# in which one of the input variables is stated as

```
new PointF[1][] { corners }
```

where corners is a previously defined a one-dimensional array of pointF

Can anybody tell me what this is specifying or what would be the corresponding VB translation?

thanks

Comment: what is c+ ? or it is c# ?

Comment: How about `New PointF(0)() {corners}`?

Comment: C# is not a difficult language to learn, at least in order to be able to understand this. Have you made any attempt to read any documentation or learn the very basics?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
Dim PointF(1) As Array = corners
```

Comment: Thanks, still having issues. I have searched but I can't seem to find a description of this syntax. What does it mean to place a variable name in brackets behind a variable type in C#?